# wpf time consuming operations and dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, listview

I have to monitor all the frames on a network. For this, I've created 2 `ListViews`, one for showing the frame names, dlcs, payloads and timestamp. I have an event which fires when a new frame is received and an update is made in the frames `ListView`.
 If i select one frame in the lv, the second `ListView` is populated with small information about the selected frame. Both, the selected line, and the whole second `ListView` are updating as that event fires and the frame payload changes. 
I have only one `Dispatcher.Invoke` for all this work, and it seems that the `GUI` stays behind with the updates. Should I use two dispatchers? 
One for the frame updates in the first `ListView` and the second for the other `ListView`? What priorities should I select for each of them? At this moment i am using the 6th level, named: Loaded.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource frames}" 
          Grid.Row="0" 
          Margin="0,1,0,1" 
          Name="lvFrames"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
          ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource itemSelector}"
          FontSize="12"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          BorderThickness="1"
          BorderBrush="Gray" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
          SelectionChanged="lvFrames_SelectionChanged">

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" Width="55"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Dir" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dir}" Width="40"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" Width="40"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="125"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Dlc" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dlc}" Width="40" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Data" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Data}" Width="150" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This is the `XAML` for the first `ListView`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource signals}" 
          Grid.Row="0" 
          Margin="0,1,-0.48,0"
          Name="lvSignals"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" 
          FontSize="12" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
          BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Signal Name"
               DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="160" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Signal Value"
              DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" Width="100"/>
           </GridView>
       </ListView.View>
   </ListView>
```

And this one for the signals `ListView`.

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML. Otherwise it's all speculations.

Comment: In XAML i have 2 ListViews with databinding to 2 ObservableCollections, one for the frames, and the second for the small details named signals, and there is the time consuming part, when i populate those 2 collections.

Comment: The Dispatcher is single-threaded. It allows code to be run at different priorities on that thread, but it is still always operating on a single thread (usually the main UI thread). If you run some long-running process on the main UI thread using the dispatcher, it will still lock up your UI. Run long-running processes on a background thread, and only update your objects or UI on the UI thread (with the dispatcher if necessary):)

Comment: There is the possibility to do heavy loads in a BackgroundWorker and update the UI after the worker has Completed the entire work, or update the UI progressively with the ReportProgress method from the Backgroundworker.